# Embedding quicktime video in qml

Tags: video, quicktime, qml

Is there a way to embed a quicktime video in qml?

I am using a WebView but it doesn't work on symbian E7:

```
WebView{
html="<html><body><object style=\"height:100%; width: 100%\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxxx?version=3&feature=player_detailpage\"><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"><param name=\"allowScriptAccess\" value=\"always\"><embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxxx?version=3&feature=player_detailpage\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" allowScriptAccess=\"always\" width=\"640\" height=\"360\"></object></body></html>"
}
```

It shows webview with plugin icon.

Comment: Are you sure this is a quicktime movie on youtube you are trying to access?

Comment: yes, if this is tried on chrome for ex it works

Answer (score 1):

add
"settings.pluginsEnabled : true"  to your code for the video to play